# Rando advice generator Code working perfectly with chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript

The below code is working perfectly fine with chrome, but not working in firefox ( after one click it just stops), no error in the console too.

```js
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next');
const advice = document.querySelector('.advice');
const adviceID = document.querySelector('.adviceID');


async function getAdvice() {
    let res = await fetch('https://api.adviceslip.com/advice')
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    let data = await res.json();
    adviceID.innerText = `Advice  #${data['slip']['id']}`
    advice.innerText = `" ${data['slip']['advice']} "`;

    
}


nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    getAdvice();
})
```

```html
<input class="next" type="button" value="Next">
<div class="adviceID"></div>
<div class="advice"></div>
```

Comment: What does the Network tab in the dev tools reveal?

Comment: @SebastianSimon
 everything is 200 and whenever i am clicking the button the fetch function is running but it's not changing the screen

Comment: Could it be that some console messages are filtered? I can imagine some kind of MIME type warning.

Comment: @SebastianSimon no i checked the console and it's also giving status 200 on every click

Comment: Works fine for me - just added the input and a couple of divs, and your code works fine

Comment: @Alucard Make sure the code is actually in its current version. Hit `Ctrl`+`F5` to reload the page with cleared cache.

Comment: Oh, that's odd - it stopped working!! Then started again!

Comment: This is the fault of caching. All these GET requests are cached. Open the console, and it “works”, because the console likely has the “Disable cache” checkbox. You could try switching to POST requests (which are never cached) or add a cache busting parameter.